Meeting people interested in crypto and programming
I have done some basic microcontroller programming in the past. I am now just starting to learn C++ and plan to move into Java and SQL eventually. I just got done reading one of Simmons books. It was a lot of fun. This subject appeals to my mind. I have to keep my brain busy all the time to keep my depression under control. I would like to meet people who have a similar interest in really old and well out of date codes as well as some of the more modern stuff. It is just a hobby for me really. Anyone know of any good places to rub elbows without getting a lot of negative attitude? Mostly looking for people to help focus my research and answer q's when something isn't working etc. Thanks in advance.

got to university classes on cryptography. for free. network over there.

Meeting people in-person, online, or both?

BTW, there is a site of Stackexchange related to puzzles (http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/). They even have a specific tag for crypto puzzles: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher

Find a CryptoParty near you!

Mostly I just meant online. I work a lot.
